# Find hash in another array and substract in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays of hashes that look like this:

```
a = [ { car_id: 1, motor_id: 1, quantity: 5 },
      { car_id: 1, motor_id: 2, quantity: 6 },
      { car_id: 5, motor_id: 3, quantity: 3 } ]

b = [ { car_id: 1, motor_id: 1, quantity: 2 },
      { car_id: 1, motor_id: 2, quantity: 3 } ]
```

I want to substract the quantities from each hash in `b` from the hashes in `a` for those hashes that have the same `car_id` & `motor_id`. So, my expected result would be:

```
c = [ {car_id: 1, motor_id: 1, quantity: 3},
      {car_id: 1, motor_id: 2, quantity: 3},
      {car_id: 5, motor_id: 3, quantity: 3 } ]
```

What is a good way to do this in Ruby? My thoughts were to iterate over `a`, and for each element find if there is any in `b` that have the same `car_id` and `motor_id`, if so, substract, and continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you first create a hash `bqty` for `b` that, for each element (hash) `g` of `b`, maps `[g[:car_id], g[:motor_id]]` into `g[:quantity]`:

```
bqty = b.each_with_object({}) {|g,h| h[[g[:car_id], g[:motor_id]]] = g[:quantity]}
  #=> {[1, 1]=>2, [1, 2]=>3}
```

Next, map each element (hash) `g` of `a` to the desired hash. This is done by merging `g` into an empty hash `h` (or `g.dup`), then, if there is an element of `bqty` with the key `key = [h[:car_id], h[:motor_id]]`, subtract `bqty[key]` from `h[:quantity]`. Note this leaves `a` and `b` unchanged.

```
a.map do |g|
  {}.merge(g).tap do |h|
    key = [h[:car_id], h[:motor_id]]
    h[:quantity] -= bqty[key] if bqty.key?(key)
  end
end
  #=> [{:car_id=>1, :motor_id=>1, :quantity=>3},
  #    {:car_id=>1, :motor_id=>2, :quantity=>3},
  #    {:car_id=>5, :motor_id=>3, :quantity=>3}]
```

An alternative to the antepenultimate<sup>1</sup> line is:

```
    h[:quantity] -= bqty[key].to_i
```

since `nil.to_i #=> 0`.

<sup>1.  How can one pass up an opportunity to use such a word?</sup>

Comment: You could use `Hash.new(0)` instead of the `to_i` business.

Comment: Good point, @Jordan, though I prefer what I have to both alternatives.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. May I ask why would you do this instead of the approach I suggested? Performance?

Comment: Yes, just performance. Creating the hash takes a little longer than searching for an element of `b` that has matching values for `:car` and `:motor`, but you only have to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what you suggested, except instead of an explicit check for `car_id`/`motor_id` it uses a hash instead.

```
ids = ->(h){h.values_at(:car_id, :motor_id)} # A function for extracting the key values
lookup = Hash[*a.flat_map{|h| [ids[h], h]}] # A map from ids -> hash w/ quantity
b.each{|h| lookup[ids[h]][:quantity] -= h[:quantity]} # Subtract each b from an a (will error if the a doesn't exist)
a == c # == true
```

Comment: Yeah, I got a bit carried away... it was fun though!

Comment: This gives the wrong answer, because there is no element of `b` that corresponds to `a[2]`. It shouldn't be hard to fix.

Comment: My apologies. I somehow missed that you were mutating `a` (even though you have `a==c #=> true`). I was looking at the return from `b.each...`, which is of course just `b`.

Comment: Yeah... mutation is the worst. But the alternative, doing a deep dup of `a` would've been annoying too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you'd find the following more intuitive:

```
    matched_result = []
    while current_a = a.shift
      if current_b = b.shift
        if current_a[:car_id] == current_b[:car_id]  && current_a[:motor_id] == current_b[:motor_id]
          matched_result << {car_id: current_a[:car_id], motor_id: current_a[:motor_id], quantity: current_a[:quantity] - current_b[:quantity]}
        end
      else
        matched_result << current_a
      end
    end
    p matched_result
```

Comment: This relies on the order of the key-value pairs in `b`. If we reverse them (`b[0], b[1] = b[1], b[0]`), this returns `[{:car_id=>5, :motor_id=>3, :quantity=>3}]`.

Comment: @Cary you're absolutely right that this solution relies on data sequence in the b array. If you do decide to change the data sequence, you just need to replace one word in the original code to make it compatible with this change. On line 3...change `b.shift` to `b.pop`. That's it.